# XML Extension not found even php-xml extension is installed

Tags: php, pecl

`sudo  pecl install trader`

shows error like this `XML Extension not found`.

```
[whitebear@jp2 ~]$ sudo  pecl install trader

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259
XML Extension not found
```

I googled around and found that this error is related with XML module or dom module.

However,in my php dom or xml is installed.

Does anyone bump into the same error??

```
[whitebear@jp2 ~]$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tidy
tokenizer
wddx
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
Zend OPcache
```

Comment: [This](http://serverfault.com/questions/589877/pecl-command-produces-long-list-of-errors) may help.

Comment: thanks that helps me.